# Multiplicative inverse of $[9]_{23}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I'm new to modular arithmetic and this has been very confusing for me. I know that in order for an element $[a]_m$ to be invertible, the GCD of $(a,m)$ has to be $1$.

I have the element $[9]_{23}$.

Now, the GCD of those two numbers is 1. We form the Diophantine equation $$9x+23y=1,$$ and after performing the extended Euclidean algorithm we have that $$1=2 \cdot 23 - 5 \cdot 9$$

which is true. The solution for $x$ is $x = \lambda_1b + t \cdot a_2$ where $\lambda_1$ is the first coefficient in the euclidean algorithm and equal to $2$, $b$ is the right side of the equation $1$, and $a_2$ is the second coefficient in the equation, which is $23.$

This gives me $$x=2+23t$$

for any integer $t$.

I need to look for the typical represent, so $x \in [0,23]$. We can achieve this by plugging $t=0$, and thus $x=2$.

However, $$[9]_{23} \cdot [2]_{23} \ne [1]_{23}$$

Where did I go wrong? The only thing my workbook did different was they **switched the places in the euclidean algorithm**

$$1= - 5 \cdot 9 + 2 \cdot 23$$ which gave them a solution that checks out. They got $$x=-5 + 23t$$, and for $t=1$ they got $x=18$, which is the multiplicative inverse.

This made me curious where I went wrong. In my mind, the only thing I did differently was switch the places of the two operands in the euclidean algorithm.

Comment: We want the inverse of $9$ modulo $23$, meaning we wish to find a number $m$ such that $9m \equiv 1 \pmod{23}$.  You seem to be trying to obtain the inverse of $23$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I'm afraid I don't understand how I might be doing that. I think the equation $9x+23y=1$ is correct, my Euclidean algorithm is correctly a linear combination which equals $1$. I just need to find a value $t$ for which $x \in [0,23]$, which is $t=0$. I still don't get the correct answer.

Comment: It looks like you misinterpreted the formula in the sentence that begins "The solution for $x$ is ..."  Specifically, you seem to have confused the roles of $\lambda_1$ and $a_2$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig That might be the case, but my workbook does state that the solutions for a linear diophantine equations are $x_1 = \lambda_1b + ta_2$ and $x_2 = \lambda_2b - ta_1$. I don't understand.

Comment: In order to answer your question, I would need to know how all the variables in your equation are defined, starting from the point where you wrote $9x + 23y = 1$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thank you your answer helped a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\lambda_1$ is the first coefficient regardless of order, then to get the correct answer, you need the correct order. You switched the order when switching sides of the equation. That gave you the wrong inputs to use the formula on .

Comment: But how do I know which is the correct order? Is it perhaps since the equation is $9x + 23y = 1$, I should express the linear combination in the same order ( $\lambda_1 \cdot 9 + \lambda_2 \cdot 23) since 9 comes first in the original equation?

Comment: Yes. To make sense of "the first coefficient" there must be a first term, but different ordering give you different results. You found that $2$ is the multiplicative inverse modulo $9$ of $23$ .

Comment: Thank you this is what I have been looking for. I thought that since the operation in the linear combination is addition, the order of operands doesn't matter.

Comment: It technically doesn't, but if you think for a moment $\lambda_1$ isn't "the first coefficient" but "the coefficient on the number you want the inverse of" so if you treat it as "the first coefficient" you must have the first term be related to "the number you want the inverse of"

Answer (score 3):

Stop at your $1=2 \cdot 23 - 5 \cdot 9$, everything after that is unnecessary. Reduce both sides modulo $23$. You get $[1]=[-5]\cdot [9]$. There you have the answer. You could say $[18]$ instead of $[-5]$ if you want, but that's not necessary in my opinion.

Comment: It is indeed a shorter and more efficient answer thank you. However I am looking for an error in my solution because I can't find it.